# How to remove unnecessary Gray space in react-native android studio emulator?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am getting unnecessary space but I want to start my code from the very top. I want to make header of my own or be able to customize the 'gray' region. How to do it? **Pls check the attached picture**

I am attaching code and picture alongwith.
[Phone Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Ptw.jpg)

> App.js code-

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

import Header from './components/Header';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Header title="I am Header" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

> Header.js code-

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>{props.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 90,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  headerTitle: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
export default Header;
```

Comment: so do you want to start your code from the mobile header ( that includes battery notification clock etc... )?

Comment: You'd need a full screen activity.  Please note that unless you're a game, a video player, or something similar this is considered a BAD thing to do-  people want to be able to see their system bar.  They want to be able to tell what time it is and see their notifications.

Comment: @NishargShah Yes correct. because i didn't write anything for that gray region

Comment: Here is the demo please look out https://snack.expo.io/@nishargshah/full-screen-demo

Comment: @GabeSechan no, you got that wrong. I want my header to take up that space so that time, notifications etc come over my header. I dont wanna hide them.

Comment: @NishargShah yes something like that. I have also done same. See my code but i am getting gray space in my emulator

Comment: can you create demo of it in snake?

Comment: Hi @NishargShah  Thank you, It seems fine on snack.io but my emulator shows the gray region. It seems the code is correct but the emulator displays wrongly. Thanks for suggesting to run demo on snack.

Comment: so you got your answer?

Comment: try 1. `SafeAreaView` or  2. `View` with `StatusBar`